# Find probability of someone who has cheated on the test and solved a question within 20% of allocated time.

Tags: probability

To check who are the students that cheat on a test, a college tries to find relations. Given the following information, what is the probability that someone who has finished the test within 20% of allocated time has cheated on the test?

1. 1% students cheat on the test.
2. 20% students solve a question within 20% allocated time.
3. 80% students that cheat on a test solves the questions in within 20% of allocated time.

My solution: Consider 500 students. Thus, 5 cheat, 100 solve in 20% of allocated time, 80% of people that cheat(i.e. out of 5) 4 of them also solve in 20% of allocated time. Thus out of 500- 4 students cheat and solve it in 20% of allocated time i.e. 4/5 out of 100. So my guess is 0.8 should be the probability.
But I'm not sure. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Let cheating in the test be the event C

Let finishing the test in 20% of allocated time be event A

Given:

P(C) = 0.01

P(A) = 0.2

P(A/C = 0.8

Applying Bayes theorem $P(C/A) = \frac{P(A/C).P(C)}{P(A)} = \frac{(0.8)(0.01)}{(0.2)}$

Putting the numbers we get $P(C/A) = \frac{4}{100}$